# How to achieve this text effect in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, text

[image: example]Free font could be 'et-book-bold-line-figures.ttf' (https://github.com/edwardtufte/et-book/tree/gh-pages/et-book/et-book-bold-line-figures).

I know in Inkscape how to duplicate a text, move it, make a path-difference and recolour it. But this seems to be more complicated.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do a difference operation for text like this.  You could instead use clones of editable text. This is non destructive and means you can still edit the text.

Here are the basics on how to set it up

1. Type some text, set the stroke and fill to "Unset Paint".

[image]

2. Make two clones of the text, and keep the original text as your clone source.
3. On the first clone set a white stroke colour
4. On the clone source in the Stroke Style set the Order to "Fill, Stroke, Markers", and use the stroke size slider to set the stroke size of the first clone.
5. For the second clone, set the fill to brown.
6. Move the two clones into place, the first clone with the white stroke on top, and the brown underneath. Move the brown text so that it just peaks out behind the white stroke of the text above.

[image]

7. Group the two clones.
8. Now, if you edit the clone source the text will update in the clones

[image]

Of course, using clones like this might be more than you need. You could also do this with just duplicates of the text with strokes and fills applied in the same way, but then it won't be so easy to edit. You'd need to edit the text for each text object separately.